# Water adhesion problem

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a bunch of plastic capillaries that come from two different production lots.
I dip them into saline solution and in the capillaries coming from the first lot the solution "mounts" a bit along the walls forming a meniscus.
This phenomenon is not observed with the second lot; there is no meniscus and the liquid surface stays flat.

What kinds of material differences might cause this, and by what physical principles would those material differences cause the presence/absence of the meniscus?

Might it be due to plastic coating?

Comment: There is no way for us to answer this unless we have more information about the production of these capillaries, and even in that case because this question is specific to a particular lot of objects it might be off topic. I tried to edit the question to make it more generally appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, meniscus angle is a function of the ratio of adhesion (how much the fluid is attracted to the wall) and cohesion (how much the fluid is attracted to itself). Therefore the more [hydrophobic](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/405378/super-repellent-plastic/) the plastic is, the less concave the meniscus will be. Hydrophobicity in plastics (and, in fact, most materials) is a function of surface geometry (more important) and chemical composition (less important).

You might consider [this reference](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/States_of_Matter/Properties_of_Liquids/Cohesive_and_Adhesive_Forces).